# No Root File Defined?

Tags: system-installation

Guys please help me on how to install ubuntu in my system.At present i am using Windows 7 ultimate version.My configuration 80GB HDD.C/:40GB,D/:20,E/:19GB.

Now I want to replace whole win7 in C drive with ubuntu OS. When I am installing it, I am getting an error message saying "No Root File Defined...please correct in the partition order.....bla bla...."so please help me on installing ubuntu...

Comment: Does anybody read the documentation?

Answer (score 3):

During the install you are asked to partition that part of the disc you want Ubuntu on. At least 1 of these partitions has to be named `/` (ie. root).

Example image:

[image]

The `ext3` partition in the image needs to have a `mount point` name `/` for the system te continue the install (assuming the 1st one had windows on it (NTFS) and the 2nd one being swap).

Comment: please explain me in clear cut step by step,so that i will install it easily....:)
i mean,i have data in D and E drives...now i want to replace C drive win7 with ubuntu....
so how i have to replace it,so that i dnt wanna loose my D and E drives data.....please provide step by step info if possible.....

Comment: All you need to know regarding this problem is in my post ;) If you want more information about installation please have a look at the many questions/anwsers on AU. If it does not help make a new question ;)